# Dart: How to mock and stub Sqflite transaction (inner callback)?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing, mocking

i am trying to mock the following method of sqlite_api.dart by (https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite):

```dart
Future<T> transaction<T>(Future<T> Function(Transaction txn) action, {bool? exclusive});
```

my implementation/adapting of the method is like:

```dart
Future<void> _transaction(Set<DatabaseLocalRequest> payload) async {
    await this._api.transaction((txn) async => {
      for (final req in payload) {
        await txn.rawInsert(req.query.sql, req.query.arguments)
      }
    });
}
```

my db_test.dart using Mocktail (https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail):

```dart
test('if [single] put succeeds', () async {
      // SETUP
      sut = DatabaseLocalProvider(db: mockDb);
      final query = Statement(sql: 'INSERT INTO Test(name, value, num) VALUES("some name", 1234, 456.789)');
      final req = DatabaseLocalRequest(query: query);

      // MOCK
      when(() => mockDb.transaction((txn) => txn.rawInsert(req.query.sql, req.query.arguments)))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => 1);

      // ACT, ASSERT
      await sut.put(req: req, bulkReq: null).then((response) => {
        expect(response, ...
      });
}); // test end
```

I got the following response from the console **ERROR**:

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Set<Set<int>>>'
```

---

How do I stub the inner `txn.rawInsert()` method that should respond with the `Future<Set<Set<int>>>` with `{{1}}`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I might not respond exactly to your question but you can mock sqflite by using a real implementation with `sqflite_common_ffi` since it works on all desktop (MacOS, Linux, Windows) on the dart VM so also in flutter and dart unit tests:

More information here: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi#unit-test-code

One solution is open a database in memory for each test so that you start with an empty database.

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_common/sqlite_api.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';

void main() {
  // Init ffi loader if needed.
  sqfliteFfiInit();
  test('simple sqflite example', () async {
    var db = await databaseFactoryFfi.openDatabase(inMemoryDatabasePath);
    expect(await db.getVersion(), 0);
    await db.close();
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! These are very good considerations that I will use for an alternative use! Especially 'sqflite_common_ffi' was unknown to me, that looks good.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
when(() => mockDb.transaction(any())).thenAnswer((_) async => {{1}});
when(() => mockDb.rawInsert(any())).thenAnswer((_) async => 1);
```

this did the trick! but it is not 100 solution, because the closure is not stubbed but bypassed.